# Coil unit testing - how to do this?

Tags: android, unit-testing, coil

Is it possible to mock coil network level when unit testing? With `MockWebServer`? Or test it somehow else? I can't find information on the Internet about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. We can use OkHttp’s mock web server. Also check out: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/image_loaders/#testing